# Sklearn Pipeline/ColumnTransformer throwing ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

I'm trying to run sklearn ColumnTransformer for individual Pipelines. My dataframe is called listings_prepared. All features are float or int. The dataframe is clean--the only issue is a few missing values which are marked Nan, so SimpleImputer should handle it...

Sklearn provides documentation [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/compose/plot_column_transformer_mixed_types.html) on running pipelines through ColumnTransformer, which is what I've followed.

First, I create the pipelines using Pipeline:

```
num_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('num_imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='median')),
    ('num_scaler', StandardScaler()),
])

disc_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('disc_imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent')),
    ('disc_scaler', StandardScaler(), disc_attribs),
])

cat_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('cat_imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent')),
    ('cat_ohe', OneHotEncoder(categories='auto', drop='first',
                              sparse=False)),
])

amen_pipeline= Pipeline([
    ('amen_imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent')),
])
```

Then, I run them through ColumnTransformer:

```
    listings_pipeline = ColumnTransformer([
    ('num', num_pipeline, num_attribs),
    ('disc', disc_pipeline, disc_attribs),
    ('cat', cat_pipeline, cat_attribs),
    ('amen', amen_pipeline, amen_attribs),
])
X_train = listings_pipeline.fit_transform(listings_explore)
```

Here's the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-511-9d5100fe0f5d> in <module>
     12     ('amen', amen_pipeline, amen_attribs),
     13 ])
---> 14 X_train = listings_pipeline.fit_transform(listings_explore_pipeline)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py in fit_transform(self, X, y)
    466         self._validate_remainder(X)
    467 
--> 468         result = self._fit_transform(X, y, _fit_transform_one)
    469 
    470         if not result:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py in _fit_transform(self, X, y, func, fitted)
    410                     message=self._log_message(name, idx, len(transformers)))
    411                 for idx, (name, trans, column, weight) in enumerate(
--> 412                         self._iter(fitted=fitted, replace_strings=True), 1))
    413         except ValueError as e:
    414             if "Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead" in str(e):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
    922                 self._iterating = self._original_iterator is not None
    923 
--> 924             while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
    925                 pass
    926 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    757                 return False
    758             else:
--> 759                 self._dispatch(tasks)
    760                 return True
    761 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in _dispatch(self, batch)
    714         with self._lock:
    715             job_idx = len(self._jobs)
--> 716             job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
    717             # A job can complete so quickly than its callback is
    718             # called before we get here, causing self._jobs to

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in apply_async(self, func, callback)
    180     def apply_async(self, func, callback=None):
    181         """Schedule a func to be run"""
--> 182         result = ImmediateResult(func)
    183         if callback:
    184             callback(result)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in __init__(self, batch)
    547         # Don't delay the application, to avoid keeping the input
    548         # arguments in memory
--> 549         self.results = batch()
    550 
    551     def get(self):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self)
    223         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
    224             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
--> 225                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    226 
    227     def __len__(self):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    223         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
    224             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
--> 225                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    226 
    227     def __len__(self):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in _fit_transform_one(transformer, X, y, weight, message_clsname, message, **fit_params)
    714     with _print_elapsed_time(message_clsname, message):
    715         if hasattr(transformer, 'fit_transform'):
--> 716             res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
    717         else:
    718             res = transformer.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in fit_transform(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    385         """
    386         last_step = self._final_estimator
--> 387         Xt, fit_params = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params)
    388         with _print_elapsed_time('Pipeline',
    389                                  self._log_message(len(self.steps) - 1)):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in _fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    270         fit_transform_one_cached = memory.cache(_fit_transform_one)
    271 
--> 272         fit_params_steps = {name: {} for name, step in self.steps
    273                             if step is not None}
    274         for pname, pval in fit_params.items():

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in <dictcomp>(.0)
    270         fit_transform_one_cached = memory.cache(_fit_transform_one)
    271 
--> 272         fit_params_steps = {name: {} for name, step in self.steps
    273                             if step is not None}
    274         for pname, pval in fit_params.items():

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Why isn't this working?